# How to create a "Math Square" puzzle with PHP?

Tags: php, math, logic

**Math Square:**
Like this one: http://www.ps-heine.de/archives/416

- A Math Square has to be solved from left to right, top to bottom.
- The order of operation rule doesnt apply.
- Each number can be used only on time.

Im loved this ones since elementary school, but unfortunately I couldn't find any books with them. Disappointed about that I thought I could try to make some by myself.

Im Still in a conceptional stage,
but let me explain the step's I've taken so far:

First I create an array `$matrix`.

- It contains an array for each row of the matrix.
- Each row-array holds the columns/cells of the actual row.
- Each cell is an array with the params "id", "type" & "value".

View an example of the array here:
http://pastebin.com/RdBmxvjq

In this example you can already see the operators.

I've got a function operator() which randomly returns one of the operators "+", "-", "*", "/".

Naturaly first including the operators and than finding numbers fitting in the matrix together with them is much easier than vice versa.

*At this point I could be already finished!*

Now I just could put in random numbers ( from an array of course, so they dont repeat themselves ), calculate the results of the rows & columns, remove the numbers and have my puzzle finished!

**If there wasn't the division-operator!**

Of course we don't want me / the final user trying to divide prime-numbers or getting decimals as result.

Now I could loop around and "bruteforce" until I find the perfect number to put in before the division-sign, but this is so... naff

I wish there's a way to make initially sure all divisions result in senseful well... results...

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Let me add some random thoughts I just had which appeared kinda senseful to me:

First of all, when I change a number in the puzzle it will take effect on the whole puzzle. So changing numbers, including all types of bruteforce, is a performance-killer (beside the fact its naff).

So a logical consequence would be to first start including numbers only where divisions occur.

We could use a number for the "product" which we first calculate by multiplicating some othe numbers, to make sure the number is no prime-number and to have a factor.

But what happens if one of the factors is a prime-number, and there occurs a division again?

If we repeatedly use a number multipicated by another number for getting a non-prime factor that would decrease the varity of numbers in our puzzle making the whole thing less interessant.

And what happens with the multiplications in the puzzle when we "reverse-engineer" it?
They automatically "become divisions" and the problem starts over.

Please let some mathematician come by calling me dumb and presenting a suprisingly easy solution...

Comment: You need a way of finding whole number factors of any other whole number. So when you come across a number followed by a division, you'd use anything from it's factors, not just any number.
I am intrigued, and will try to find an algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$num = integer; // the number before /
$factors = array(1, $num); // allowed numbers after / (1 and $num are always allowed)

// loop through whole numbers up to the original $num
for($i = 2; $i < $num ; $i++) {
    // if $i can devide $num, save it and the other factor
    if($num % $i == 0) {

        // if $i is there, we have gone through all factors, no need to loop anymore
        if(in_array($i, $factors)) {
            break;
        }

        // save $i and $num / $i
        $factors[] = $i;
        if($i != $num / $i) { // do not save $i twice
            $factors[] = $num / $i;
        } 
    }
}
```

And use a random number from the $factors array for the number after the "/".

About filling up the numbers (pseudocode):

```
R = row, C = collumn
for(R; R < max rows; R = R+2) { // R+2 to skip sign rows
    for(C; C < max cols; C = C+2) { // C+2 to skip sign columns

        if(C-1 == / && R-1 == / && C >= 2 && R >= 2) {
            find factors of C - 2;
            find factors of R - 2;
            select number from subsection of these (should be at least 1)                 
        } 

        else if (C-1 == / && C >= 2) {
            select number from factors of C-2
        }

        else if (R-1 == / && R >= 2) {
            select number from factors of R-2
        }   

        else {
            select any number (maybe select just non-prime numbers here)
        }
    }
}
```

I hate to admit, this is all the brain power I have for today... I will check it out later to see if there are any interesting developments.